# How to add a new Firestore document with a nested collection in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

How would I go about adding a new document in Firebase/Cloud Firestore with a nested collection?

```
const createDocument = () => {
        const documentName = prompt('Enter document name:');
        if (documentName) {
            db.collection('despacito').add({
                name: documentName,
            })
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [data model doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data), Collections and documents are created implicitly in Cloud Firestore. Simply assign data to a document within a collection. If either the collection or document does not exist, Cloud Firestore creates it.

So no need to actually create a document with a nested collection.

Per the [subcollections documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) to reference a new document in a subcollection you can reference it as:

```
const messageRef = db.collection('rooms').doc('roomA').collection('messages').doc('message1');
```

As you are using the .add [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), it should be something like:

```
db.collection('despacito').doc('documentName').collection('subcollectionname').add({
                name: nesteddocumentName,
            })
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: no problem, feel free to upvote/accept the answer for reference for future users with same issue